# Pandas - Updating value in row based on condition with .apply()

Tags: python, pandas, loops, apply

Simplified, I would like to use a function to check a condition on a row and set the value accordingly:

```
def helper(row):
    if row["A"] == "TEST":
         row["B"] = "WOW"
     else:
         row["C"] = "NO_GO"


moddf = df.apply(helper, axis=1)
```

I can do this using iterrows() but .apply should be MUCH faster to iterate over 1M rows in a df.

Comment: Just return the row, though `apply` is likely not the most efficient way here.

Comment: `apply` will be basically just as slow, it's still a loop when you inevitably call it with `axis=1`. Likely you want to use `np.where`, instead with a loop over the small number of columns that need to be set differently, instead of the 1M rows.

Comment: `apply` is one of the last resources you should reach to. Use the `pandas` and `numpy` methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need (and shouldn't use) apply:

```
# toy data
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':['TEST','NO'],
              'B' : ['A','B'],
              'C' :list('12')})

s = df['A']=='TEST'

df.loc[s,'B'] = 'WOW'
df.loc[~s, 'C'] = 'NO_GO'
```

Output:

```
      A    B      C
0  TEST  WOW      1
1    NO    B  NO_GO
```

Comment:  That would do it